# How can I search a specific word on Google at the same time avoiding it in a phrase?

Tags: search, google-search

*This is my first post here, so Hi! and don't hesitate to migrate my question to anywhere else, wherever it might be more appropriate*

To better understand my question, here is an example -

I want to search for all occurrences of the term *peanut* on the *Wikipedia* avoiding all the occurrences of *peanut butter*. Here I can use *double quotes* for peanut and *site:XYZ* , but using the minus *'-'* symbol for the phrase doesn't work (I am guessing because of the basic contradiction that I want *peanut* and not want it at the same time, maybe).

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Can you snip the result you received when you did your search?

Comment: Looks like it was some virus after all and the search tricks were absolutely fine. Do people here want me to edit the question in a Q&A form or should I just delete it altogether. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually articulate your search phrase, but this seems to work for me when googling:

```
peanut -"peanut butter" site:en.wikipedia.org
```

EDIT:
[search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36vXG.png)

I opened the top seven pages and ran a search on 'peanut butter' with no success.

Comment: That's exactly what didn't work, double quotes, I assume don't work for phrases?

Comment: you must be specific with what phrase it should not include (I pressume).

Comment: Looks like it was some virus after all and the search tricks were absolutely fine. Thanks a lot...